# hello world project error when run in opendaylight

Tags: maven, sdn, maven-archetype, opendaylight

I am trying to create the hello world project in ODl  but got the same error.when build the hello world project white `mvn -nsu clean install` or `mvn clean install` it has error.
I followed two different procedures in [link1](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Controller_Core_Functionality_Tutorials:Application_Development_Tutorial) and [link2](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html).also im used this code for archetype

```
 mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
 -DarchetypeVersion=1.6.0-SNAPSHOT \
 -DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/ \
 -DarchetypeCatalog=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/archetype-catalog.xml
```

my error

```
[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.hello :: hello-artifacts ... SKIPPED
  [INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.hello :: hello-it .......... SKIPPED
  [INFO] hello .............................................. SKIPPED
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 38.402 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-23T13:30:56+01:00
  [INFO] Final Memory: 54M/293M
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-maven)
  on project hello-api:     Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
  [ERROR] 
  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
  [ERROR] 
  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

how to can resolve this problem?

Comment: Notice it says "Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed".

Comment: @ Tom Pantelis I do not know why it's failing im used this [link](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Controller_Core_Functionality_Tutorials:Application_Development_Tutorial) and this [video](https://youtu.be/2wTEuNyxspY) but again it has error

Comment: But the message indicates there are messages above what you pasted that should indicate the specific cause. What are those? It may be enforcing a certain minimum version of maven.  Keep in mind that those links/videos are a few years old and are likely outdated in some respects.